# Visual Studio Code: Display JSdoc for attribute

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, vscode-extensions

Is there a way so when moving the cursor over the `x:10,`, it would display the JSdoc of `Point.prototype.x`. The goal is to have the same JSdoc than when I mouse over `pt.x`.

If it is not possible with the current version of Visual Studio Code, would it be possible to do so by writing my own extension? If so, what part of the vscode namespace API is related with this?

[image]

```
class Point {
    /** The x property */
    x:number;
    /** The y property */
    y:number;
}

/** Prints a point. 
 * @param pt The point
*/
function printPoint(pt:Point){
    console.log(pt.x,pt.y);
}

printPoint(<Point>{
    x:10,
    y:10,
});

let pt = new Point();
pt.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

I work on JavaScript and TypeScript support for VSCode.

This looks like a bug. I've opened [this issue against TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13963) to track this.

Once the issue is fixed in TypeScript, you can try it out by installing a nightly TypeScript build (`npm install typescript@next`) and following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions) to configure your workspace.

Here's VSCode's implementation of hover for TypeScript and JavaScript in case you are interested: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/typescript/src/features/hoverProvider.ts All the language features come from the TypeScript server.